# Codeigniter 3 send email without smtp

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3

I am not receiving an email, though everything seems fine. May be hosting issue? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Here is my code

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('info@domain.com', 'Name');
    $this->email->to($seller_email);
    $this->email->subject('This is subject');
    $this->email->message('This is message!');
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

print_debugger function returns empty.
Let me know you guys comments.

Comment: You have no email config there. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences

Comment: What I need in configuration? I tried adding basic configuration as well. Can you tell me what configurations are needed in basic email sending?

Comment: Are you using xampp or wamp?

Comment: If you are not using an smtp server, then you revert back to the build-it PHP function mail(). This requires the ability to send email from your server somehow, which is specified in the "sendmail_path" parameter in the php.ini file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @crafter, I am using network solutions hosting. Would mail() be able to send from it without any settings?

Comment: If your OS has the sendmail executable installed then yes. The built-in PHP mail function will use (for example) sendmail -f .... to send the email.

Comment: I saw the there is email helper function as well, which uses mail(). I think i should try that.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect solution is as below:

**Step 1:**

Download PhpMailer for CodeIgniter from below link.

https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer

**Step 2:**

Extract.
Put `third_party`, `libraries`, `helpers` and `config` folder into your CI application folder.

There will just index file(s) in each folder that will ask you to replace. 
Click replace and continue.

**Step 3:**

Open `application/config/email.php`

And do some updates according to your email account. I am using gmail, so I am giving gmail settings as below.

```
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp'; // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // if you are using gmail
$config['smtp_user']        = 'youremail@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'sdkfjsk089sdfskKJ'; // App specific password
$config['smtp_port']        = 465; // for gmail
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 5;
```

**Step 4:**

Now, in your controller where you want to send email. Use below code and its all done.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('youremail@gmail.com')
     ->reply_to('youremail@gmail.com')
     ->to(someone@somedomain.com)
     ->subject("Subject")
     ->message("Your Message")
     ->set_mailtype('html')
     ->send();
```